# Using Lists in replacement of Paragraph and Header tags

Tags: html, css, list, seo, semantic-markup

Researching lists, it appears they have an SEO advantage. After reading [this article](http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=185), particularly the section on 'definition lists', I can't help but notice that definition/[description lists](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) look very similar to a typical large body of text (header -> paragraph, header -> paragraph etc).

Obviously CSS can style the `<dl>` and `<dt>` tags as needed, so my question is:

If it gives you an SEO advantage, why isn't everyone using definition/description lists for the bulk of their online content?

Comment: `Paragraph` and `list` both behaves differently and for `SEO` I depend on `h1` element (tho an element is not the only way to gain SEO), it has grater precedence and it should be only one on a page for `SEO` benefit, AFAIK.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 If there is a natural pecking order for SEO, then perhaps using header tags (assuming they rank higher) should perform better in site navigation than lists?? I know it is trying to 'cheat' the system, but isn't that what navigation as lists is doing anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it appears they have an SEO advantage

What should this be, a "SEO advantage"? Good web search engines try to understand the content of a page. The page author defines the structure of the content by using HTML, which might help search engines. Now, if the content contains a list, it is a very good idea to use the corresponding HTML element for lists → here you have your "SEO advantage". In the same way, you use the heading HTML elements if you have a heading in your content. And yes, these also offer "SEO advantages" … for headings, that is.

But this doesn’t mean that there is any benefit in using list (or heading) elements for content that is not a list (or a heading). Otherwise …

```
<ul>
  <li>Why</li><li>not</li><li>use</li><li>lists</li><li>for</li><li>words</li><li>in</li><li>sentences</li><li>?</li>
  <li>O</li><li>r</li><li> </li><li>l</li><li>e</li><li>t</li><li>t</li><li>e</li><li>r</li><li>s</li><li>?</li>
</ul>
```

Always use HTML elements exactly in the way they are defined in the specification. Otherwise all consumers (browsers, search engines, screen readers, …) will have a hard job.

And this doesn’t mean that it would be inappropriate to use `dl` in your case. It depends on your content. A `dd` can certainly contain `p` elements. But note that in HTML5 you [can’t](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element) use headings in `dt`.

Comment: Thanks @unor. Why is there a huge trend on people using lists for menu items? This is the source of my statement (or assumption at least) about lists having an SEO advantage. A menu is a menu, yet people use it differently to manipulate the system. Otherwise why not go semantic instead of using list tags...

Comment: @John: Why wouldn’t you use a `ul` for the site navigation? What a site navigation tells the visitor, is: "Hey, my site is divided into 5 sections (=pages), here you go". I think using a list for such a menu is appropriate; even more so when there might be sub-sections (e.g. think of a drop-down menu). -- See the [HTML5 spec about `nav`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-nav-element), which contains examples using `ul` for the navigation links. -- See also on css-tricks.com: [Wrapup of Navigation in Lists](http://css-tricks.com/wrapup-of-navigation-in-lists/)

Comment: Well explained @unor - I see the connection especially regarding sub-pages etc. The practicality makes sense, I think the context is what is throwing me off. IMHO I still think it should always be `<menu>` before it is `<ul>`, but I'm not in the mood to write a 'Dear html5...' letter. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Patented System of Document Ranking](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=1&p=1&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&S1=7,716,216.PN.&OS=pn/7,716,216&RS=PN/7,716,216) based on semantic distance between terms in a document. It covers the following **aspects of lists in SEO**:

- > If both terms appear in the same list item, the terms are considered
  >   close to one another.
- > If one term appears in a list item and the other term 
  >   appears in header, this pair of terms may be considered to be 
  >   approximately equally distant to another pair of terms that appear 
  >   in header and in another of the list items.
- > Pairs of terms appearing in different list items may be considered to
  >   be farther apart than the pairs of terms falling under 1 and 2.

[Read more on lists in SEO](http://pitstopmedia.com/sem/list-items-seo).